# C++ Why does the position of x,y matter while using float?

Tags: c++

So, I don't know how to explain this. I'm a C++ newbie and I would be grateful if somebody could explain this to me. I wrote **float y,x** instead of **float x,y** and the program worked just fine. The compiler didn't report any errors, but the program didn't do what it was instructed to do. It ignored the whole 'while' loop and went straight to the end. I fixed it by changing the position of x and y, *but why does the position of x,y make a difference*?

```
        #include <cstdlib>
        #include <iostream>

        using namespace std;

        int main() 
        {

        float x,y;  /*This is the problem. Why does float y,x make a difference?*/

        int s=0;
        int s1=0;
        int max=0;


        cout<<"Unesi stanje racuna:"<<endl;
        cin>>y;


        while(x!=0)
        { 

                    cout<<"Unesi vrijednost:"<<endl; 
                    cin>>x;

                    max==x;


                   if (x>0) s=s+x;
                   if (x<0) s1=s1+x;
                   if(x>max) max=x; 
         }


        cout<<"suma pozitivnih :"<<s<<endl;
        cout<<"suma negativnih :"<<s1<<endl;
        cout<<"najveci unos je :"<<max<<endl;
        cout<<"ukupno stanje je: "<<s+s1+y<<endl;

        return 0; }
```

Comment: Using uninitialized variables leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: The order of declaration does not make a difference. What *does* make a difference is using uninitialized variables. You have forgotten to assign a value to `x`. (Also, you should not compare floating-point values for equality. You will end up disappointed.)

Comment: @CodyGray I think he assigns the value of y to input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The position doesn't matter at all. `float x, y;` is the same as `float y, x;`.
What matters here is that your program is ill-formed and thus you can't rely on the output.
You check for `x != 0` but x hasn't been initialized, which is undefined behaviour. You probably meant `y != 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize both x and y variables, before using the comparison in the while loop. Otherwise it's just random if it works.

Additionally, you should compare your float variable with a float value (0.0, instead of just 0)